# Unsafe pointers, emptyInterface word

Tags: go

I am trying to understand Go `unsafe.Pointers` internal. In case when there is only one field in the struct and returns me a pointer to the `Foo`, returns a pointer to the `Bar`.

Is there a way to actually return allways pointer to the `Foo` not `Bar`? It works only when `*Foo` or `Foo` has more than one field. Is it compiler optimization, or is it related with Heap/Stack allocation?

```
type Bar struct {
    ID    int
    Name  string
    Price float64
}
type Foo struct {
    Bar *Bar
}

aFoo := Foo{
    Bar: &Bar{},
}

//xunsafe.AsPointer implementation:
//
// func AsPointer(v interface{}) unsafe.Pointer {
//  empty := (*emptyInterface)(unsafe.Pointer(&v))
//  return empty.word
//}

fmt.Printf("Foo ptr: %v, Bar ptr: %v\n", AsPointer(aFoo), unsafe.Pointer(aFoo.Bar))
//Output: Foo ptr: 0xc00010a060, Bar ptr: 0xc00010a060
```

Edit: I am using the `go1.17`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `&aFoo` to get a pointer to the `Foo`.

The type `unsafe.Pointer` is a special type understood by the compiler. The compiler allows conversions between `unsafe.Pointer` and other types that are not [normally allowed by the language specification](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Conversions).

Regarding xunsafe.Pointer: You see different results for

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar *Bar
}
```

and

```
type Foo struct {
    Bar *Bar
    ASecondField int
}
```

because those types have different representations when stored in an interface value. Values larger than a word are copied to memory private to the interface value and the interface value stores a pointer to that memory. The `xunsafe.AsPointer` function does have code to handle both of representations.

Comment: Yes, I realized that they have different representations, but my questions are: Is it due to compiler optimizations? I don't think it is because of the Heap/Stack since in both cases `Foo` should be allocated on the stack.  And also, how Go knows if that ptr is actually `Foo` pointer (when Foo has more than 1 field) or `Bar` pointer (when Foo is not a pointer and has only one field). Is it due to the `tflag`, `ptrToThis` or some other `rtype` field?

Comment: @KamLar Values larger than a word are copied to memory private to the interface value.  The interface value stores a pointer to that memory.